# Firefox: Drop-down menus (<select> elements) don't register "change" events when the parent div is transformed with transform3d?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, css, css-transitions

All,

I've run into something that looks like a bug in Firefox.

I have a `DIV` element that contains a `SELECT` element:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <select id="ddm">
        <option value="a">AAA</option>
        <option value="b">BBB</option>
        <option value="c">CCC</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

The `DIV` is then transformed using `transform3d` (actually, using just translateX, but I get the same results either way).

```
#wrapper {
    background: yellow;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    -moz-transform: translateX(200px);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(200px);
    transform: translateX(200px);
}
```

After the `DIV` is transformed, changing the `SELECT` element doesn't seem to register an `onchange` event. (Technically, I'm using jQuery and the .change() function, but that doesn't seem to matter):

```
$('#ddm').change(function (e) {
    alert ('Select changed!');
});
```

I.e., the alert is never triggered.

Here's a JSFiddle to demonstrate:

Case 1 (No tranform3d, onchange events fired):

http://jsfiddle.net/b5fNb/8/

Case 2 (tranform3d, onchange events fired in Chrome and IE, but not Firefox):

http://jsfiddle.net/b5fNb/12/

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I see the same as you, in Firefox 18. I can't even click the options on the drop-down to actually change the select, but I can use the up and down arrow keys to change the selected option, but nothing is updated in the other div, like you said.

Comment: yeah confirm this. this is killing my isotope layout :\

Comment: here's the bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=827890

Comment: I've seen these before. They also had a problem with webfonts in `select` elements that would reload the page if clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately - this is a bug in Firefox:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=827890#c2

So - for now - it looks like there won't be an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
$('#ddm').change(function (e) {
alert ('Select changed!');
}).on("keyup",function(e) {
$(this).trigger("change");
});
```